# APIView stopping another view from working

Tags: django, django-views

I have the following urlpatterns and APIViews for getting JSON data. They all work and return data as they should except for the last one 'pollutant_daily_means'. When I remove the view for 'site_daily_means' then the 'pollutant_daily_means' returns the data that it should.

If I remove just the 'site_daily_means' above it then it still doesn't work, so it must be something to do with the site_daily_means view interfering somehow.

```
url(r'^api/daily-means/$', views.daily_means.as_view(), name='daily_means'),
url(r'^api/daily-means/(?P<url>\w+)/$', views.site_daily_means.as_view()),
url(r'^api/daily-means/(?P<poll>\w+d+)/', views.pollutant_daily_means.as_view()),

class daily_means(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        means = DailyMean.objects.all()
        serializer = DailySerializer(means, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

class site_daily_means(APIView):
    def get(self, request, url):
        means = DailyMean.objects.filter(url=url)
        serializer = DailySerializer(means, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

class pollutant_daily_means(APIView):
    def get(self, request, poll):
        means = DailyMean.objects.filter(poll=poll)
        serializer = DailySerializer(means, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Can anybody see any clear reasons for this from the above urls and views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that matches `(?P<poll>\w+d+)` will be matched first by `(?P<url>\w+)`, so the `site_daily_means` view will run.

You could fix this by changing the url pattern for `pollutant_daily_means`, e.g. to:

```
url(r'^api/daily-means/poll/(?P<poll>\w+d+)/', views.pollutant_daily_means.as_view()),
```

Note that `\w+\d+` is probably unnecessary in this case. You could simplify it to `\w+` since you already filter `DailyMean` on the `poll` field.